# Query with special characters doesn't work in Active Record

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, activerecord, character-encoding

I have a simple function like this:

```
function get($name) {

  //SELECT ID FROM USERS WHERE NAME = $name
  $this->db->select('ID');
  $this->db->limit(1);
  $this->db->from('USERS');
  $this->db->where('NAME', $name);

  $query = $this->db->get();

  $row = $query->row();
  return $row->ID;  
}
```

Everything works fine except when I have special characters in `$name` (Ñ or Á, for instance). In that case, the query doesn't return any row.

I've used `$this->db->last_query()` to try the query directly on SQL console and its returning a perfectly valid query which returns the expected value. To me, that means that the query is ok, but there is some encoding problem between Codeigniter and SQL Server.

I've checked the DB encoding configuration and its:

```
$db['odbc']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['odbc']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

The collation of the DB is `Modern_Spanish_CI_AS` and the NAME field is set in `databse default`.

What am I missing? Could be some problem in the PHP configuration?

Comment: you need to use like instead of where $this->db->like('NAME', $name);

Comment: what is the collation of your database??

Comment: use mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: what is the collation of your database & table `USERS` & `NAME` field??

Comment: @devpro I've just tried, same result.

Comment: @IlanHasanov Tried, same result.

Comment: #Daniel: is database collation is utf8_general_ci?

Comment: The collation of the DB is `Modern_Spanish_CI_AS` and the NAME field is set in `databse default`.

Comment: @DanielMarín change it to utf8_general_ci

Comment: Can't find it in the collations list. It seems that it goes from Urdu_100 to Uzbek_latin.

Answer (score 0):

Change database collation to `utf8_general_ci`

And check `USERS` table collation and `NAME` field collation too.

```
 ALTER DATABASE <database_name> COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ;

 ALTER TABLE USERS ALTER COLUMN NAME varchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

You can change from management studio too.. It is under options menu
[image]

Comment: Can't find that collation. It goes from Urdu_100 directly to Uzbek_latin.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. You can see it in the question or in the tags.

Comment: Sorry for that.. I'll give you those queries too

Comment: I've tried the queries, but they don't work. I get a lot of "Incorrect Sintax" errors. Probably they are for MySQL,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98131/discussion-between-simhachalam-gulla-and-daniel-marin).

Comment: Tried, same result :(. I mean, 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
$this->db->like('NAME', $name);
```

or

in header file

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

> **If you use Codeigniter `form_open()` it will generate `<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"` this part automatically.**

Comment: Sorry, but I've already tried the "like" method. You can see it in the first comment. And the file already has that header. Thanks anyway